# qualifier, multiplicity and database

Tags: uml

[image]

Can I interpret this class diagram like this? A certain file can have many different names in a directory. The names in a directory must not be duplicate. The number of file with certain name in a directory is zero or 1. But if I also want to say that a directory can store many files and a file can be stored in many directories. Does this diagram show that information too? According to this diagram, there will be 3 tables in the database (directory, File and the join table). .
Directory(Did, Dname) where Did is primary key.
File (Fid, Fsize) where Fid is primary key.
Then in the join table, there must be (Did, Fid, name) and the combination of (Did,name) must be unique . Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is almost perfect. There's just one nit to pick: the multiplicity on the left represents how many *directories*, not how many *names* are associated with a file. There is nothing that restricts how many file names in a directory can represent one file. In other words, you could have several names in one directory for the same file, which is possible on a UNIX-based file system for example. Nonetheless, your three tables and column uniqueness constraints represent everything perfectly.

Comment: ● Without qualifier, a file can be only one time in one directory because there can be only one link between one pair of objects. But using qualifier, a file can be in a directory more than one time using different names because Files are linked to names within directories (not linked to directory), so multiple occurrences within a directory are possible.

Comment: So in my opinion, the left multiplicity should be the number of names, not the number of directory. I don’t understand that. For the left multiplicity, the qualifier has to be neglected and for the right multiplicity, the qualifier has to be considered?

Comment: Eliminate the qualifier and change the right multiplicity to *. The meaning of the multiplicity on the left remains the same.

Comment: So if the JoinTable(Did, Fid, name) and the combination of (Did,name) must be unique, what are the primary keys of this table?